# As soon as I start my activity, application is terminated

Tags: android, compiler-errors

My application just works fine on some devices but when I load it on some other devices it openes but when I start an activity (that needs `screenOrientation="portrait"` also), it is terminated. Any idea?

```
02-06 11:47:52.390 D/SensorManager(19387): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41fa8a60
02-06 11:47:52.390 D/Sensors (19387): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
02-06 11:47:52.390 I/Sensors (19387): sendDelay --- 200000000
02-06 11:47:52.390 D/SensorManager(19387): JNI - sendDelay
02-06 11:47:52.390 I/SensorManager(19387): Set normal delay = true
02-06 11:47:52.545 D/dalvikvm(19387): GC_CONCURRENT freed 288K, 9% free 13814K/15175K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 29ms
02-06 11:47:52.575 D/SensorManager(19387): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41e23990
02-06 11:47:52.670 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19387): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
02-06 11:47:52.755 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19387): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
02-06 11:47:52.755 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19387): getExtractedText on inactive Input
Connection
02-06 11:47:52.830 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19387): finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
02-06 11:47:52.955 D/dalvikvm(19387): GC_CONCURRENT freed 361K, 9% free 13938K/15175K, paused 2ms+13ms, total 32ms
02-06 11:47:54.450 D/SensorManager(19387): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41e23990
02-06 11:47:54.450 D/Sensors (19387): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
02-06 11:47:54.450 I/Sensors (19387): sendDelay --- 200000000
02-06 11:47:54.450 D/SensorManager(19387): JNI - sendDelay
02-06 11:47:54.450 I/SensorManager(19387): Set normal delay = true
02-06 11:47:54.720 W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19387): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Post logcat that is relevant. You could try filtering it based on application.

Comment: Search the red lines in LogCat :)

Comment: I didnt get what you mean Rajesh.

Comment: logs are related to unregistering listener. Please also share some code with us when the crash is happening and what is written in another screen

Comment: I dont know where the crash happens, it is a coloring game and on the next screen, where the error comes, coloring things happens and what does "logs are related to unregistering listener" means?

Answer (score 0):

Where your screenOriention information set?

If you set programatically , maybe this give problem. You counld set AndroidManifest file in  tags.

Comment: I set it in AndroidManifest file:  <activity
            android:name=".Picture"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

Comment: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41e23990

Comment: This error sensor error for orientation. Because orientation run with sensor. Please check activity class. Have you config changes override method in activities?

Comment: I dont have any changes about orientation in my activity.

Comment: Have you layout-port and layout-land file? If you have only layout-port file this will be problem.

Comment: I have only one file. I dont have layout-land. Nuri kardes.